# bower pulling zip file from the cache even though it has found file to be stale

Tags: caching, bower, artifactory

I am having a problem referencing Zip files in bower.json, and getting bower to update the installed package when the Zip file changes.

---

My company uses a local bower registry like this in .bowerrc

```
"registry": "http://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/bower/bower-virtual"
```

My bower.json file has a dependency entry like:

```
"mypackage": "http://mycompany.com:8080/artifactory/bower-local/mypackage-1.7.1.zip"
```

where the zip file is a modified version of a package downloaded from github (for some legal reasons, we had to make a change, and the pull request hasn't yet been accepted).

I do a "bower **install** mypackage" and everything is great.

Now, I make a change to the zip file. I can't change the version number or the file name; I am just changing a line of code in a JS file inside the Zip file. The expectation is that bower can use the e-tag to tell whether the zip file has changed.

I type "bower **uninstall** mypackage" then "bower **install** mypackage", expecting to get the new code. However, this pulls from the (stale) cache rather than grabbing the new code EVEN THOUGH bower detects the stale zip file (using e-tag) and claims to be updating the cache.

However, when I check bower_components, it's the same code as before.  Here's what I see:

```
$ bower uninstall mypackage
bower uninstall     mypackage

$ bower install mypackage
bower mypackage#*                cached http://mycompany.com:8080/artifactory/bower-local/mypackage-1.7.1.zip#e-tag:2af72bda2b
bower mypackage#*              validate e-tag:2af72bda2b against http://mycompany.com:8080/artifactory/bower-local/mypackage-1.7.1.zip#*
bower mypackage#*                   new version for http://mycompany.com:8080/artifactory/bower-local/mypackage-1.7.1.zip#*
bower mypackage#*               resolve http://mycompany.com:8080/artifactory/bower-local/mypackage-1.7.1.zip#*
bower mypackage#*              download http://mycompany.com:8080/artifactory/bower-local/mypackage-1.7.1.zip
bower mypackage#*               extract mypackage-1.7.1.zip
bower mypackage#*              resolved http://mycompany.com:8080/artifactory/bower-local/mypackage-1.7.1.zip#e-tag:85ddfe2ee0
bower mypackage#*               install mypackage#e-tag:85ddfe2ee0
```

As you can see, there was a cache miss, and although a "new version" was detected, the old version remained in the cache, and my installed package continue to have the old code.

Same thing happens when I do "bower **update** my package".

The only workaround is to do "bower **cache clean** mypackage" before every install, just in case the Zip file has been updated.

I realize there are other ways to structure this development environment, without referencing a Zip file over http. But this is what we have, and bower supports Zip files -- it just doesn't replace them in the cache when it detects that one has changed.

Is this just a bower bug or am I doing something incorrectly?

[originally posted at https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1945 but not a lot of traffic over there it seems]

Comment: Why did you define the dependency entry in this form? if Artifactory is configured as your Bower registry, you do not need to use a URL for the dependency. Having a dependency in this form means that Bower will use the URLResolver which is very limited.

Comment: Right, normally we would not use a URL, and would do it the "normal" way.  In this case, I work for a large firm that has unusual legal requirements, and the software for specific packages has to be hosted in-house.  We have to take the Zip file off github, make a few changes, and put it on an internal server.  That's why we have to use this form.

Comment: That said, the bug here reproduces without artifactory.  You can create two dummy packages, A and B.  Zip up B and have A depend on B.zip.  Install A.  Then change something in B.zip and try to get A to pick up the change -- although bower detects the change and claims to download, extract, and install B, none of this actually happens unless you remove B from the cache.